# Shopify Dawn Theme - Show max variant price on featured collection ( homepage )

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I just started a website in shopify (Dawn Theme)

In homepage under feature products it displays lowest variant price, how can I set this to maximum price, here is my website link for better understanding [www.atdukaan.com](http://www.atdukaan.com)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found a solution. Head to `price.liquid`, and change line `#17` from:

`assign target = product`

to:

`assign target = product.variants.first | default: product`

You can also select a different variant from the `variants` array in order to showcase your desired default pricing.